# How to get files from Salesforce using Python

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce, beatbox, django-salesforce

I am using Python/Beatbox to access Salesforce cases.

```
service = beatbox.PythonClient()  # instantiate the object
service.login(...)  # login using your sf credentials

query_result = service.query("SELECT Id, AccountId, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id='xyz'  ")
```

I'm interested in a specific case:

```
print query_result[0].Id
```

Get attachments...

```
att_result = service.query("SELECT Id, ContentType, Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId= '" + str(query_result[0].Id) + "'")
```

So far the results are good. Now I want to download the files uploaded to the case.
What should be my query? I tried following and its always empty..But Im sure the case has files as well as attachments..

```
doc_result = service.query("SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, Title FROM AttachedContentDocument  WHERE Id= '" + str(query_result[0].Id) + "'")
```

I also tried the document object and still no success. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Salesforce API, but in your last line where you're retrieving the attachment, `doc_result`, should you be using the ID of the attachment(s), so you'd use `str(att_result[0].Id)` instead of `str(query_result[0].Id)`.

Comment: I guess that you are looking for: ContentDocument and not AttachedContentDocument. At least in my 'Case' it works

Comment: Utm, To access contentdocument how do we link with case and its documents. Is it case.ID = ParentID.ContentDocument? This is what Im missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can get not more than one Attachment by one request in any Salesforce API. To be sure that you don't an attachment, get the Attachment.Id first, then get the body by a loop

```
SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = '...'
for ...
    SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = '...'"
```

A) **SOAP** API (Beatbox): Get the Attachment as a normal long base64encoded field.

```
import base64
ret = service.query("SELECT Id, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = '...'")
blob = base64.b64decode(ret)[0]['Body'])
```

The query should expect one row because the output is restricted to one row if the "Body" field is present.

B) If **REST** API is used ([simple-salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/) package) with the same queries, the value of `Body` or `VersionData` fields is a URL of the form `'/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Attachment/<object_id>/Body'` which can be downloaded by GET request.

C) [Fetch Salesforce Attachment content with **django-salesforce**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46052952/448474)

---

Objects useful for Binary Large OBjects are Attachment, Document and ContentVersion.
These useful queries allow to get a binary large object (Attachment or Document) as a normal long field by **SOAP** API (Beatbox). The `ContentVersion` object allows to store more versions of the same data. `Attachment` has a parent object. `Document` is without any parent object. Useful queries: (read restrictions by API above)

```
SELECT Id, Body FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = '...'
SELECT Id, Body FROM Document WHERE ParentId = '...'
SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
att_body = att_result["records"][0]["Body"]
att_url = base_url + attachment_body
att_text_result = requests.get(url, headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % session_id })
```

Refer this for session_id: https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce