# How to fetch Salesforce Attachment file content with django-salesforce?

Tags: python, django, salesforce, beatbox, django-salesforce

I'm developing a Django 1.11 app serving as a UI for some Salesforce Objects using `django-salesforce` for the communication with Salesforce.

I have to give users the option to download files from Salesforce Attachment objects related to their Contact.

```
# Django Attachment model on my_app/models.py

...

class Attachment(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Contact, models.DO_NOTHING,
                               sf_read_only=models.NOT_UPDATEABLE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='File Name')
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    body_length = models.IntegerField(sf_read_only=models.READ_ONLY)
    body = models.TextField()

...
```

On this Attachment model I can access the rest URL for the file content on the `body` field, but not the actual content.

Is there a way of getting file content from the Attachment without having to implement an OAuth client just for this?

Comment: Please edit your question, write your Attachment model, the query and the unexpected output what you see, to be it generally understandable: " from what I see". The information can be simplified for the purpose of example, but should be present. It is also better to replace the initial words "Basically I need" by what you are doing/trying. You can be inspired by some successful questions at SO site or by [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This all is probably why the question has been down voted and flagged to close.

Comment: @hynecer thanks for your suggestions, I hope is better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A)** by REST API request encapsulated by `handle_api_exceptions`

```
from salesforce.backend.driver import handle_api_exceptions
# from salesforce.dbapi.driver import handle_api_exceptions  # can be changed soon to this
from django.db import connections

session = connections['salesforce'].sf_session
rows = Attachment.objects.filter(...)
for row in rows:
    url = session.auth.instance_url + row.body
    blob = handle_api_exceptions(url, session.get).text
```

**B)** You can get SOAP client (requires Beatbox) by

```
from salesforce.utils import get_soap_client
import base64

soap = get_soap_client('salesforce')
for ...:
    ret = soap.query("SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = '...'")
    blob = base64.b64decode(ret)[0]['Body'])
```

---

Useful related answers are:

- [How to get files from Salesforce using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900697/how-to-get-files-from-salesforce-using-python)
- [Uploading Attachments to Salesforce API via Beatbox, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312509/uploading-attachments-to-salesforce-api-via-beatbox-python?rq=1)

**EDIT** I expect that you mean User = some Contact, not a Contact necessarily related to SFDC object User with some form of paid license. They should download only through your site, not directly, for security reasons. Any OAuth can not probably improve it.

Comment: worked just fine with the REST API, thanks! Just one note though, maybe you are referring to a different version of the `django-salesforce` but shouldn't it be `from salesforce.backend.driver import handle_api_exceptions` ?

Comment: Yes, now `salesforce.backend.driver` and it can be changed soon to  `salesforce.dbapi.driver`.

Comment: regarding your edit, users on the portal are tracked as Contacts on Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a dedicated endpoint to stream blob of file

```
{{endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/connect/files/{{file_id}}/content
```

**Parameters:**

1. endpoint: instance URL
2. version: API version
3. file_id: contentDocument record id